# WSO2 REST - ESB - REST

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm wondering for solution to my Issue but I didn't find anything that can help me :(

THIS IS MY ISSUE:
I'd like to call a remote REST web service by passing it trought an ESB to log the client call on DB. 
I'd like to pass a POST query var to my remote ws too, for example name=value & name2=value2!

I make a proxy service but I don't know how I can append the query variable to IT.

I can contact correctly remote ws with this proxy but I can't pass a POST VAR because I don't know how to do that.

I make a below curl call by client shell:

```
curl -k -i http://neanb330:8281/services/BioframeProxyService
```

in my proxy service I have this endpoint :

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/emboss_matcher/run

BUT this service require two params in input and put out a jobid that I want to write in out sequence for client.

Have I to make a REST API?
How I can Log client call on db?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This post describes how to process rest requests within WSO2 ESB in detail with examples. 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/get-cup-coffee-wso2-way/

This is the official documentation that explains rest url mapping

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs

Comment: I have just see the first article but It Have a SOAP WS to backend. I have A REST SERVICE in backend instead. I cant find how I put POST var to my beckend REST SERVICE!

Comment: Use REST_URL_POSTFIX property to append and construct query string, http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2012/07/invoke-rest-endpoint-from-soap-client.html, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties  and in this post it is achieved through class mediator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523977/wso2-synapse-setting-a-url-parameter

Comment: tnx for answer, REST_URL_POSTFIX help me to much in order to achieve a response to BackEnd service. But It don't put in right manner the "jobid" at the end of my endpoint address becoause I recive NOT_FOUND response But I expected FINISHED. MY api is:

   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{jobId}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
                   value="get-property('uri.var.jobId')"
                   scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/emboss_matcher/status/"/>

Comment: OK I make error on atribute to properties tags, it want expression="get-property('uri.var.jobId')" in place of value and it work. This for GET request Now i try with POST request.

Comment: CAN ANYONE help me to pass POST vars and process this in madiator api? I do with this: <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/{aseq}/{bseq}">
      <inSequence>
          <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat(get-property('uri.var.aseq'),get-property('uri.var.bseq'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
          <send>
             <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/emboss_matcher/run/"/>
             </endpoint>
          </send> but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how you can send data to your end point using curl then this is the way

```
curl -v --request POST -d '<Values><name1>ABC</name1><name2>Smith</name2></Values>' -H Content-Type:"text/xml" http://neanb330:8281/services/BioframeProxyService
```

Then you can get the values to ESB as shown below

```
<property name="name1" expression="//name1/text()"/>
     <property name="name2" expression="//name2/text()"/>
```

Comment: Hi tnx for reply, I'd like to send My POST data in Api and not by curl, But I can't do that. i want pass My param to api by this curl call: curl http://192.168.43.68:8281/run/asequence=FASTA/bsequence=FA
STA/email=maforast@libero.it and get this in api  with this:  <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat(get-property('uri.var.aseq'),get-property('uri.var.bseq'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/emboss_matcher/run/"/>
            </endpoint>
But It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for both GET and POST in Rest to rest scenario.

This for POST. I USE a proxy service and a curl call:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="BioframeProxyServiceRunBis"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <switch source="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD">
            <case regex="GET">
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            </case>
            <case regex="POST">
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            </case>
            <default/>
         </switch>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/emboss_matcher/run/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

curl -k -X POST https://neanb330:8244/services/BioframeProxyServiceRunBis -d asequence=FASTA -d bsequence=FASTA -d email=maforast@gmail.com -v
```

I don't find solution for save rest call to DB